# Compound Profit per trade vs Time on Stocks with target profit

Tags: stocks, compound-interest, profitability

Any good Spreadsheets or explanation that track compound profit for stocks with time considered? I am trying to journal my stock trades and set some goals.  We know compound interest is powerful.  I want to use that and target 15% on stocks over x time. Reinvest that and keep hitting 15% targets.  Example by 1000 shares at $10 for $10000.  I sell at $11.50 for $11500.  I keep reinvesting and repeat. Sometimes I protect my interest and sell 1/2 my stocks if I think there is momentum but capture my profit goal.  My goal is to take $10000 and getto $60,000.  How many trades do I need to make to actualize this?  Time is the other factor.  Most compound explanations explain over time because they are talking bout holding a stock.  I'm trying to shorten my periods and use # of trades vs time as exampled in mutual funds. Thanks folks

Comment: "We know compound interest is powerful"  Just a note, are you "day trading"?  If so "compound interest" is not a thing, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how many times you need to compound 15% to result in a factor of 6, it’s simple algebra.

X=log6/log1.15 = 12.82

A return of 15% per year will give you $60,000 on your $10,000 in just under 13 years.

Or ignore time, and just go with 13 instances of a (compounded) 15% return.